# find function that meets certain criterias

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

I need a function that meets certain criterias.

This is what I've got so far:

```
(tan^-1(x*2-1.5)+1)/1.5
```

It looks like this:

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2okg.gif)

And it is nearly perfect, except that I want exactly:

1. x = 1 --> y = 1
2. x = 2 --> y = 1.5
3. x = 0 --> y = 0

I can replace either of the 1.5's in the function above to satisfy either 1 or 2, but don't know how to find numbers that will satisfy both, though I have a hunch that it's some fancy number, involving PI.

so, I guess my question is: What function looks like the above graph and satisfies my three statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no numbers $a, b$ so that the function $f(x) = \frac{\arctan(2x + a) + 1}{b}$ satisfies all three properties.

The condition $f(0) = 0$ implies $\arctan(a) + 1 = 0$, i.e.
$$a = \tan(-1) \approx 1.56.$$
But this, combined with the condition $f(1) = 1$, implies 
$$b = \arctan(2 + \tan(-1)) + 1 \approx 1.42.$$
With these values for $a$ and $b$
$$f(2) \approx 1.54.$$